# Toggle Button, Traducir funcion c# a delphi

Tags: c#, delphi

Estoy intentando hacer un `Toggle Button/Toggle switch` en Delphi 7 definiendo un nuevo componente heredado de `TwwCheckBox` pero encontré algo similar en `C#` y estoy traduciendo las funciones que hacen esto

Recurso: [Toggle Button](https://rjcodeadvance.com/toggle-button-custom-controls-winform-c/)

```
    private GraphicsPath GetFigurePath()
    {
        int arcSize = Height - 1;
        Rectangle leftArc = new Rectangle(0, 0, arcSize, arcSize);
        Rectangle rightArc = new Rectangle(Width - arcSize - 2, 0, arcSize, arcSize);
        GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();
        path.StartFigure();
        path.AddArc(leftArc, 90, 180);
        path.AddArc(rightArc, 270, 180);
        path.CloseFigure();
        return path;
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
    {
        int toggleSize = Height - 5;
        pevent.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
        pevent.Graphics.Clear(Parent.BackColor);
        if (Checked)
        {
            pevent.Graphics.FillPath(new SolidBrush(onBackColor), GetFigurePath());
            pevent.Graphics.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(onToggleColor), new Rectangle(Width - Height + 1, 2, toggleSize, toggleSize));
        }
        else
        {
            pevent.Graphics.FillPath(new SolidBrush(offBackColor), GetFigurePath());
            pevent.Graphics.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(offToggleColor), new Rectangle(2, 2, toggleSize, toggleSize));
        }
    }
```

Pero al estar traduciendo a Delphi me di cuenta que algunas clases como `GraphicsPath` , `PaintEventArgs pevent`, `FillPath`, `SolidBrush` no existen como tal en Delphi, hay variantes pero quisiera saber si hay posibilidad de hacer esto en Delphi 7?

Aquí estoy tratando de seguir el patrón que tiene c#, la razón porque la que estoy haciéndolo así es porque es la formas mas sencilla que encontré en c#

```
uses
   SysUtils, Classes, Controls, StdCtrls, wwcheckbox, Graphics, Variants, Forms, Dialogs, Types;

type
   TinToggleButton = class(TwwCheckBox)
   private
    { Private declarations }
     ...
     procedure SetOnBackColor(Value: TColor);
     procedure SetOnToggleColor(Value: TColor);
     procedure SetOffBackColor(Value: TColor);
     procedure SetOffToggleColor(Value: TColor);
     procedure GetFigurePath(): TCanvas;
   protected
     ...
   public
     ...
   published
     { Published declarations }
     ...
  end;

  procedure Register;

 implementation


  ...

  procedure TinToggleButton.SetOnBackColor(Value: TColor);
  ..
end;

  procedure TinToggleButton.SetOnToggleColor(Value: TColor);
  ...

    procedure TinToggleButton.SetOffBackColor(Value: TColor);
    ...

     procedure TinToggleButton.SetOffToggleColor(Value: TColor);
     ....


   ...

 procedure TinToggleButton.Paint;
 ...

 end.
```

Comment: No son *palabras reservadas*, son **clases**. Pertenecen al `namespace System.Drawing`, [link a la documentación oficial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing?view=net-5.0). Tienes que buscar librerías equivalentes en Delphi. Si buscas *'draw in delphi 7'* en google, tienes muchos recursos para empezar.